# last day of month question

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I have the following query which is giving the last day of month by passing month name and year but dont know how to get first day in the similar fashion.

```
declare @month int, @year int
select @month=1,@year=2011

select Convert(varchar(20),dateadd(year,@year-1900,dateadd(month,@month,0)-1), 105)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have experience with SQL Server, but based on your code, I would guess the answer would be something like:

```
declare @month int, @year int
select @month=1,@year=2011

select Convert(varchar(20),dateadd(year,@year-1900,dateadd(month,@month-1,0)), 105)
```

Answer (score 0):

Keeping it in the datetime domain, find 1st day of following month and then subtract one day

```
SELECT
    dateadd(day, -1, dateadd(year, @year-1900, dateadd(month, @month, 0)))
```

Almost anything with CAST or varchar is non-deterministic and isn't language/@DATEFORMAT safe